# Is it possible to run Java3D applications on Nvidia 3D Vision hardware in windowed mode?

Tags: java, directx, nvidia, java-3d, stereo-3d

Thanks to JohnnyO it was already answered if it is possible to run Java3D application in conjunction with nVidia 3D vision:

[Is it possible to run Java3D applications on Nvidia 3D Vision hardware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017131/is-it-possible-to-run-java3d-applications-on-nvidia-3d-vision-hardware/9416411#9416411)

His approach also worked fine for me. *But it is restricted to full screen mode.*

His thread is already a few months old, and now during the last few weeks nVidia improved its drivers for 3D Vision: Now it is possible to run many applications also in windowed mode. If you are using professional hardware like the nVidia Quadro cards or ATI Fire GL, you know and appreciate the windowed mode already for a very long time.

Now, with the latest updates of the nVidia drivers (I have currently installed 295.73) it is also possible to run many applications like the nVidia Picture Viewer, the Stereoscopic Player etc. in windowed mode.

http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2311

Normally DirectX 9 applications should run in windowed mode, as you can read on the previously mentioned nVidia page. And I think Java 3D is a DirectX 9 application. If I use:

-Dj3d.debug=true

Then the console says:

> [j3d] Using DirectX D3D 9.0 or higher.

(And of course no one seems to be working on the improvement of the DirectX implementation of Java 3D these says.)

Did somebody meanwhile find out the trick how to run Java3D in Stereo windowed mode? I tried it, but I failed so long. I think this will be a very important argument *pro* Java 3D, if we solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed when I played around with this was that the 3D vision drivers weren't kicking in, even when I thought I had everything set up correctly.

One hack we found was that the nVidia drivers were actually only configured to support specific video games on their whitelist, but the whitelist matching was just based on exe names.

After lots of problems and frustration, we renamed our Java wrapper from myprogram.exe to something from the whitelist, things worked much better.  I think for a while, or exe was named BatmanAC.exe in testing or something like that.  This seemed to make the nVidia drivers much more permissive to what we wanted to do.